# java, вычисление факториала

Tags: java, math

Здравствуйте.
как получить полное число, которое выходит за пределы типа long, и соответственно выдает не правильный ответ. скорее всего будет ещё какое либо число которое будет состоять из двух типов лонг но только для того что бы расширить регистры. не пойму как это делать.

```
public class CalculateFactorial{
public static void main(String[] args){
    factorial fact = new factorial();
    System.out.println(fact.factoring(23));
}
static class factorial{
    long result = 1;
    public long factoring(long x){
        for(long i = 1; i<=x; i++){
            result *= i;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849813/large-numbers-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вручную делать не надо, есть тип Biginteger

```
public static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger n) {
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;

    while (!n.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        result = result.multiply(n);
        n = n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь. сейчас буду разбираться как это за взаимодействовать с написанным кодом.

Comment: я уточню. В таком виде для больших чисел будет долго работать. Если нужна скорость - нужно умножать примерно одинаковые по длине числа и использовать любое логарифмическое умножение.